# Return Output Param of a Stored Procedure inside another Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to find out how to return the output parameter of a stored procedure when executing the stored procedure inside another stored procedure:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE Test1

 EXEC SpWithOutputID -- Outputs @ID

 SELECT @ID as ID -- Output @ID now being used in this SP
```

This is of course not my code, but just an example, is it possible to do this?

Example 2:
     --Here @ID returns Null

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE Test1
 As 
 DECLARE @ID int

 EXEC SpWithOutputID @ID = @ID OUTPUT -- Outputs @ID

 SELECT @ID as ID -- Output @ID now being used in this SP
```

Example 3:
     --Here @ID returns an Int

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE Test1
 As 

 EXEC SpWithOutputID -- Outputs @ID
```

Comment: You'll need to clarify... is `@ID` in `SpWithOutputID` an actual `OUTPUT` parameter, or is it selected like the last line? Big difference, and terminology is important.

Comment: the sp there has no `OUTPUT` param, but it still Outputs a value, so i guess i have to give SpWithOutputID an Output Param, I get it. Thanks again Aaron, what would i do without you..? =]

Comment: You'll need to show the code that you expect to run inside `SpWithOutputID`. You should also clarify the question, because you have a different definition of `output param` from most of your readers. If you need to return a single scalar value back, then you should make the inner SP return an `OUTPUT` param, not a result set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this isn't really an output parameter issue at all, but rather a result set, then taking a guess that `SpWithOutputID` does something like this (returns a `SELECT` with a single row and single column):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SpWithOutputID
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT ID = 4;
END
GO
```

Then `Test1` could look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ID INT;

    CREATE TABLE #x(ID INT);

    INSERT #x EXEC dbo.SpWithOutputID;

    SELECT TOP (1) @ID = ID FROM #x;

    DROP TABLE #x;
END
GO
```

---

---

But doesn't that look really messy to you? It really should work this way for single, scalar values:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SpWithOutputID
    @ID INT OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @ID = 4; 
END 
GO
```

Now it is much simpler to consume what is really an output parameter now:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @ID INT;

    EXEC dbo.SpWithOutputID @ID = @ID OUTPUT;

    SELECT @ID;
END
GO
```

Comment: In dbo.Test1, don't you have to Declare @ID ?  Does it actually work, because i'm getting a NULL value over here.

Comment: Sorry, corrected. I grabbed that from the previous example when you led me to believe you were using an output parameter...

Comment: Yes, it works. http://yfrog.com/kja44p Why would you accept the answer and then ask if it works?

Comment: Ok it's like that, but @ID is returning a NULL in Test1, but when i run it `SpWithOutputID` without any param, i get the right @ID returned.  Hmmm...

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. What is different about your query than what I showed in the screen shot? Your description sounds the opposite to me. If you run `SpWithOutputID` without any parameters, then there is no way you get any value in `@ID` in `dbo.Test1`.

Comment: You either need to use the ***FIRST*** example of `dbo.Test1` I provided, or you need to ***CHANGE*** `dbo.SpWithOutputID` to the second example I posted. You can't use the ***SECOND*** example of `dbo.Test1` against the ***FIRST*** example of `dbo.SpWithOutputID` and expect some magic to change your `SELECT` to an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: ie, if i run your 2nd examples, `dbo.SpWithOutputID` in a Query it works, it returns an ID.... But when I run `dbo.Test1` it returns a NULL, even though it should be the ID..

Comment: Ok it was giving me problems because i had a default value `@ID int = NULL` in `SpWithOutputID` so i had to remove it, anyways, it works now. Thanks again!