# How to return or get output value from stored procedure which is executing inside procedure main (get this in c#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, output

How can I know if a stored procedure that is executed within another procedure returns an error or exception, a void?

In this code I show only one **(EXAMPLE)** where I have a stored procedure and inside it I get data from another stored procedure, but if for some reason it returns empty or something happens inside the stored procedure `storedp_SearchTurn` as I can compute the value that returns this procedure before obener the one that returns the main procedure `storedp_Process`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[storedp_Process] (
    @id numeric, 
    @type_time      char(1)
 )
As

declare     @terminal       varchar(30),
    @id_employee    numeric,
    @hour           datetime,
    @date       datetime,
    @inic           numeric

set  @terminal =   host_name()
set  @inic = convert(numeric,replace(left(right(convert(varchar(80),getdate(),9),14),12),':',''))

-- Other stored procedure
exec storedp_SearchTurn    @hour,
                     @turn  output ,
                     @date_valid output

print @turn

Declare @period  numeric(10)
Select  @period = period from setup
            where convert(char(10),date_valid,111)=convert(char(10),@date,111)  and id_turn = @turn 

--The code continues, this is just an example
--The code continues, this is just an example
--The code continues, this is just an example
--The code continues, this is just an example
--The code continues, this is just an example
```

Because even if `storedp_SearchTurn` executes and returns empty or something happens, anyway `storedp_Process` will return 0 if a problem does not occur in `sp_Process`. I need to capture some error or exception of the procedure that runs inside the other.

I get the output values ​​well and use them within the main procedure, but I need to obtain those output values ​​that belong to the secondary procedure, get them in C#, in order to inform the user if something happened during the process.

In C # I tried adding these parameters as output, but since they do not belong to the main procedure when executing, the exception jumps that the stored procedure has more arguments than those specified.

**NOTE:** The stored procedure works perfectly, I just need to obtain those output values ​​of the secondary procedure in C#

But I must not modify the stored procedure, the company has created it that way and it works perfectly, I just need to know if at some point the output values returned empty, or have data, or if an exception occurred and get this in C#

I also found these related topics, but none of them answered my question:

[How to return or get output value from stored procedure which is executing inside another proceed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22931854/how-to-return-or-get-output-value-from-stored-procedure-which-is-executing-insid)

[Return Output Param of a Stored Procedure inside another Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286446/return-output-param-of-a-stored-procedure-inside-another-stored-procedure)

[Executing a stored procedure inside another stored procedure using Select Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808524/executing-a-stored-procedure-inside-another-stored-procedure-using-select-query)

[Get the value of a stored procedure inside another stored procedure with select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888546/get-the-value-of-a-stored-procedure-inside-another-stored-procedure-with-select)

[How to call stored procedure inside another stored procedure and set the values as in variable in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457081/how-to-call-stored-procedure-inside-another-stored-procedure-and-set-the-values)

[Stored procedure executing another stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388155/stored-procedure-executing-another-stored-procedure)

Comment: Nobody is going to read through link after link of stuff to help you. It is not at all clear to me what you are trying to accomplish here. In the meantime I would suggest you stop using sp_ as prefix (or even better no prefix at all). http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: ok thank you, i will improve the explanation

Comment: Should I remove links from related topics? , I placed them so that readers know that I have taken my time looking for information.

Comment: You should reword your question so that it is clear and concise.

Comment: So let me see if I understand this. You have a procedure which during it's execution calls another procedure. Your outer procedure currently does not have any means of validating the inner procedure execution. You need to somehow validate that the inner procedure actually returned a value. But you are not allowed to make any changes to either procedure. Does that sound like an accurate description?

Comment: Correct, I should not make changes in the procedures, if the internal procedure does not give a value, the main procedure is executed anyway but the required results are not obtained, so I must obtain the result of the internal procedure to inform the user that missing a fact or something like that.

Comment: You can't. It is actually impossible without making some changes.

Comment: In c # I have to know when the output values of the internal procedure return empty or have data, I need to obtain those values in c # WITHOUT MODIFYING THE EXISTING STORED PROCEDURES, then it will not be possible :(

Comment: You could try implementing the logic of storedp_Process in c#, and call storedp_SearchTurn from there (based on the output).

Comment: You don't have access to those parameters in the return of the outer one. Therefore what you want to accomplish is impossible without changing the procedure code.

Comment: That's what I need, but I do not know how I have added the parameters as output in c # but when executing it says that I am providing more arguments than those requested by the procedure. Because those output values are not from the main procedure, and in c # I just execute the main procedure.

Comment: That is what I am telling you. You can't. You would have to expose those variables as output parameters in your main procedure. Or what I would suggest is a better idea is to add some validation inside the inner procedure and have it throw an exception if something does not go right in the inner procedure.

Comment: "Exposing the variables as output parameters" were the words that escaped me; Nicely put.

Comment: at least from c # can I have access to the return value of the internal procedure?

Comment: You only have access to what is exposed through the output  parameters of `storedp_Process`. If it was redefined as `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[storedp_Process] (@id numeric, @type_time char(1), @turn output, @date_valid output)` then you could.

Comment: You need to understand the **c runtime/call stack** http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-question-run-time-stack-usage/

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I will strive to achieve it, in programming everything is possible.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I know if a stored procedure that is executed within another procedure returns an error or exception, a void?

[TRY...CATCH (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql)
[@@ERROR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-transact-sql)
[IS NULL (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql)

You could try something like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[storedp_Process] (
...
BEGIN TRY  
    exec sp_SearchTurn    @hour,
                          @turn  output ,
                          @date_valid output
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    RAISERROR (0, 0, 0, 'An error has ocurred during sp_SearchTurn.')
    RETURN
END CATCH;   

IF @@ERROR != 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR (0, 0, 0, 'An error has ocurred during sp_SearchTurn.')
    RETURN
END

IF @turn IS NULL OR @date_valid IS NULL
    RAISERROR (0, 0, 0, 'An error has ocurred during sp_SearchTurn.')
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Thanks, but I must not modify the storage procedure, the company has created it that way and it works perfectly, I just need to know if at some point the output values returned empty, or have data, or if an exception occurred see it in c #

Comment: You need to specify this in your op above.

Comment: Sorry for the inconveniences